# Unsupported Fortran 90 compiler or Fortran 90

Tags: r, linux, fortran

I want to install the `iClusterPlus` R package. I've installed the dependencies but it is still showing an error.

```
 conda install -c conda-forge gcc gfortran_linux-64 fortran-compiler gfortran f90nml
```

> BiocManager::install("iClusterPlus")

Traceback:

```
Bioconductor version 3.16 (BiocManager 1.30.19), R 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Installing package(s) 'iClusterPlus'
trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.16/bioc/src/contrib/iClusterPlus_1.34.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 21234751 bytes (20.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 20.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘iClusterPlus’ ...
** using staged installation
 This package has only been tested with gfortran.
 So some checks are needed.
 R_HOME is /root/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/R
Attempting to determine R_ARCH...
R_ARCH is
Attempting to detect how R was configured for Fortran 90....
    Unsupported Fortran 90 compiler or Fortran 90
    compilers unavailable! Stop!
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘iClusterPlus’
* removing ‘/root/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/R/library/iClusterPlus’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmptilSDJ/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘iClusterPlus’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I don't know anything about R (and not much about conda), but did you install R via conda as well, or was that installed stand-alone or from distribution packages? And why are you running conda as root?

Comment: Is your conda environment activated correctly? It looks like Autoconf couldn't find gfortran in the path.